# Error in screen-Orientation Plugin in iOS

Tags: cordova, screen-orientation, cordova-3

I'm new to *phonegap* and one problem I'm getting in using *Phonegap* Screen-Orientation plugin for iOS. The [plugin on GitHub](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/ScreenOrientation) is not working for *phonegap* `2.9.1.`

The Error is `Property allowedOrientation not found on object of type CDVViewController in ScreenOrientation.m file`

**What should be done to remove this error ?**

Comment: i also used [https://github.com/acti0nm4n/Phonegap-Orientation-iOS] this plugin but its also not working. There is an error in Appdelegate.m file and also in Orientation.m file.